# How do I find out when a node was added to an availability group?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

Ideally, I am looking for T-SQL that returns two columns: the node name, and the date/time that node was added to the availability group, for all nodes in a given availability group.

Answer (score 6):

This is as far as I can see not possible with a single T-SQL statement as individual nodes hold only their own create date.

The [sys.availability_replicas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-availability-replicas-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) page makes reference to a column *create_date*. This is the datetime value of when the node was added.

To find the create_date for each replica you would need to first connect that replica and query the table for that instance only as below.

```
SELECT [replica_server_name],
    [create_date]
FROM [master].[sys].[availability_replicas]
WHERE replica_server_name = @@SERVERNAME
```